# Как разбить строку на элементы массива в зависимости от типа символа PHP

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

**Помогите, пожалуйста, составить универсальное регулярное выражение для разделения строки на числа, сочетания букв идущих подряд и пробел.**

Есть строка, соответствующая почтовому коду Соединенного Королевства. Необходимо разбить ее на части и сформировать из них общий массив в том же порядке, в каком они записаны в строку. Каждая часть должна соответствовать:

- букве или нескольким буквам, идущим подряд, без чисел и других символов, в частности пробела, до первого НЕ подходящего символа
- одной или нескольким цифрам (числу), идущим подряд, до первого НЕ подходящего символа
- другому символу (в моем примере это исключительно один вероятный пробел, я представляю его как не буква и не цифра)

Условно, элементов массива может быть неопределенное количество, но они ограничены шаблоном почтового кода королевства. Вот картинка отлично описывающая шаблон:

[image: шаблон почтового кода Соединенного Королевства]

<sup>Позаимствовано у [www.getthedata.com](https://www.getthedata.com/postcode)</sup>

где:

- **L** - буква
- **N** - цифра
- **A** - цифра или буква
- **SPACE** - пробел
- Отметка **Optional** над символом означает что он не обязательно будет присутствовать.

  ---

  1. Пример 1:

     Код *SW1A 1AA* должен после преобразования стать массивом со
     следующим набором элементов:

     ```
     [ 'SW', '1', 'A', ' ', '1', 'AA' ]
     ```
  2. Пример 2:

     Часть кода *SW1A* должна стать массивом со следующим набором
     элементов:

     ```
     [ 'SW', '1', 'A' ]
     ```
  3. Пример 3:

     Часть кода *SW22 3* должна стать массивом со следующим набором
     элементов:

     ```
     [ 'SW', '22', ' ', '3' ]
     ```

---

**Постскриптум**: Особенную сложность для меня представляет то, что на части может разбиваться как целый почтовый код, так и отдельная его часть, вплоть до пустой строки. Не являясь экспертом в регулярных выражениях, эта задача мне оказалась не под силу :( Возможно есть более простое универсальное решение, чем использование функции `preg_split`?

Comment: [`preg_match_all('~[a-zA-Z]+|\d+|[^\da-zA-Z]+~', $s, $chunks)`](https://ideone.com/7T3ABZ)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно токенизировать строку следующим образом (см. [онлайн-демо](https://ideone.com/Q9kZZy)):

```
$strs = ["SW1A 1AA", "SW1A", "SW22 3"];
foreach ($strs as $s) {
  if (preg_match_all('~[a-zA-Z]+|\d+|[^\da-zA-Z]+~', $s, $chunks)) {
    print_r($chunks[0]);
  }
}
// - Array ( [0] => SW [1] => 1 [2] => A [3] =>   [4] => 1 [5] => AA )
// - Array ( [0] => SW [1] => 1 [2] => A )
// - Array ( [0] => SW [1] => 22[2] =>   [3] => 3 )
```

Регулярное выражение тут ([см. демо](https://regex101.com/r/dfsyqC/1))

```
[a-zA-Z]+|\d+|[^\da-zA-Z]+
```

Оно находит

- `[a-zA-Z]+` - одна или более латинских букв
- `|` - или
- `\d+` - одна или более цифр
- `|` - или
- `[^\da-zA-Z]+` - - один или более символов, отличных от цифр и латинских букв

Если нужна поддержка Юникода, используйте `'~\p{L}+|\p{N}+|[^\p{N}\{L}]+~u'`.

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас опробую.

Comment: Еще раз огромное спасибо, особенно за детальное разъяснение, работает отлично :)